# Why Relational database cannot be scaled horizontally

Tags: mysql, sql, horizontal-scaling, rdbms, nosql

I know this question has been asked quite a few times, but I have not got any satisfying answer.

I have read many blogs and most of them say that RDBMS cannot be scaled horizontally. The only way to deal with it is by buying bigger machines.

Then I read why they can't be scaled horizontally. People say because they provide solid, mature services according to the ACID properties. My argument to that is can't we drop an RDBMS to provide ACID properties for specific tables. Is that the only reason that it can't be scaled horizontally and we have to consider NoSQL databases.

The second argument that is put up is that NoSQL databases store data as a single unit whereas RDBMS stores data across multiple tables. Thus one piece of data may be in one system and another piece of data which it is referring may be in another system. Hence scaling RDBMS distributedly becomes difficult. My question to them is why can't we store all the related data in a single table rather scattering it across multiple tables if the situation demands. If NoSQL can store data as a single unit in a single collection, why can't RDBMS store data as a single unit in a single table. (For eg, why an order has to be split into order table, customer table and payment table. Why can't they be clubbed into a single table, the way a NoSQL would have stored)

This also allows developers to develop without having to convert in-memory structures to relational structures.

In short, can we make an RDBMS behave like a NoSQL database and make it scale horizontally?

Comment: Yup stick everything into a blob - best of luck getting it out again though.

Comment: Teradata is a commercial distributed RDBMS, operating from the early 80's. If it exists, it is probably possible.

Comment: It's hard to answer without repeating the blogs you read. ACID forces you to check a lot of thing (you should try to do some examples, it might make it clearer!) and rdbms rely heavily on it, which makes it complicated if the data is unstructured and spread out everywhere (but not impossible, clusters and e.g. json exist). If you remove (some of) these checks, you can e.g. store everything where you want it, even have offline nodes. If google results or facebook lists are fast, but not 100% accurate, you can live with it. If your bank would think the same way, you might complain.

Comment: You can design your database however you please.  In fact, you can even use a non-relational model using software that supports relational models.

Answer (score 2):

First - what do you mean by 'scaling horizontally'?

To me - scaling horizontally is what we all do in MPP (Massive Parallel Processing) databases - like Vertica, Teradata, DB2 Parallel Edition, NonStop SQL, etc.: You have a very big table, which you distribute evenly across all nodes of your MPP cluster, based, usually, on the hash value of the primary key, or something similar. This is what Hadoop and all other Map-Reduce architecture does, too (while often being less effective, at least as of now).

(just editing to clarify): If you have 10 nodes in your cluster, your big tables all are distributed to have one tenth of their data on each node. Scaling, now, would be to add, for example, 10 nodes, and re-distribute the data so that each table has 1/20 of its data on each node. And MPP databases scale linearly; this means that by doubling the number of nodes, with the same data volume, the queries will now run twice as quick.

You seem to mean something different - and I'm curious on what you might mean.

As to RDBMS having to split everything into several tables:

The 'R' in RDBMS stands for 'Relational'. Before entering a discussion of all this, you should read a basic tutorial on *relational algebra*. A Relation simply is a set of objects that can all be described with the same attributes. With that, all objects have the same attributes/colums/fields. As soon as this rule is violated, it is not a relation / table anymore.

I strongly suggest that you take a training on relational theory and relational databases, even before starting to play with SQL.

It's a big, big world of its own that you will have the opportunity to explore. And it all boils down to set theory and Boolean and relational algebra. And you can do so many things with it ...

Your question here is just like asking why a bicycle has two wheels.

Or am I missing something?

Marco the Sane

Comment: Hi @marcothesane. Your answer suggests that relational detabses can be scaled horinzaontally. By horizontally I mean adding more nodes. But most of the docs says that RDBMS are meant to run on a single node. You can read this here https://www.couchbase.com/nosql-resources/why-nosql. This is the official docs of couchdb. I am want to know why these NoSQL databases claim that RDMBS cannot be scaled to several nodes.

Comment: "RDBMS" is a wide enough term to avoid a lawsuit

Comment: Hi Anliket. Well, it seems strange what misleading info you can get out there. Databases like Oracle, DB2 UDB standard, SQL Server standard, are indeed databases running on one (usually big) machine. But Oracle Exadata, for example, runs on many nodes. And databases like Teradata, DB2 Parallel Edition, SQL Server Parallel DW, and, above all, my favourite, Vertica, run on MPP (Massive Parallel Processing), shared-nothing, clusters. The smallest cluster is usually 3 nodes, and they scale linearly if you add nodes. Just Google on MPP and see what you find.

Comment: Hi @marcothesane, I recognize some of the MPP examples as OLAP-specific RDBMS. Is there any OLTP MPP database in this list? NoSQL approach, IMHO, has an edge on raw performance in web scenarios because it forces you to group all the data for a specific user/document/whatever in a way that ensures that all the info are retrieved from the same server. This could be also implemented on a MPP RDBMS (having a single table with all the info or having all the related tables share a common shared hash key): however, it would mean that you're emulating on a RDBMS the NoSQL approach (with pro&cons)

Comment: There is a fantastic OLTP MPP database platform, which is very popular in Stock Exchange sites: NonStop SQL, owned by Hewlett Packard Enterprise, ex Tandem. And DB2 Parallel Edition can also be configured for OLTP workloads and is an MPP. And also OLAP databases can perform "node pruning", which is the term for what you're referrring to. For example, in a dimensional setup, a big dimension Product is segmented/distributed by HASH(product_id), and so is the fact table. (and all other dimensions are small, hence replicated across the nodes).

Comment: If I now SELECT for product_id=42, the query optimiser knows that the hash value for 42 boils down to node 13, and it will route the fetch request to that node only. There's no emulation of NoSQL. NoSQL just emulates MPP databases, using the key of the key/value pair as the distribution key across many nodes. MPP databases do that since the 1970s ...

Comment: Hi @marcothesane, to clarify I know how hashing works but my experience comes especially from Teradata  that it's hardly the best choice as a web backend (I'll look for NonStop SQL, sounds interesting). What I have seen in TD is that trying to get some performance in web scenarios brings to some denormalised and peculiar schemas, as a m:n relation would bring multiple nodes to exchange info before an answer can be returned. These "denormalised" schemas look like hierarchical database model (1960s) and NoSQL document based model.

Comment: @marcothesane let me also clarify that I'm more on the SQL camp, but I think that NoSQL has its place in some specific context where you can trade RDBMS flexibility with NoSQL raw speed on simple "return me all the info related to this entity" queries (not to mention that it might be more cost effective).

Comment: By the way, I realize that you have indeed given examples of horizontally scalable databases both in OLAP scenarios (e.g. Vertica, Teradata) and in OLTP scenarios (e.g. NonStop SQL), so I think you have correctly answered the initial question ("Can RDBMS scale horizontally?")

Comment: On the sense of platforms like NoSQL: I agree "if you have a hammer, your whole world is a nail" is not a good attitude; and therefore I won't put highly structured, and equally structured, data into anything that is not relational, and I will always put data of inconsistent structure or not structured at all, and non-atomic data, like BLOBs or CLOBs, into something more object-oriented. And that's where a platform like NoSQL comes in. Ferraris and Land Rovers are good cars. You won't win at the Hockenheim Ring with a Land Rover; you won't wade through a river with a Ferrari.